# Building dynamic DropDownList with Event Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I want to build a dynamic `DropDownList` and add some list item. 
With below code I can do it.

```
protected void BuildDynamicDropDown()
{
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.ID = "newDDL";
    ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += dynamicDDL_SelectedIndexChanged;
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("stack1", "stack1"));
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("stack2", "stack2"));
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("stack3", "stack3"));
    ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(ddl);
}

protected void dynamicDDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this part of code should trig another dynamic dropdown
}
```

But **I want to use that SelectedIndexChanged event in order to change another dynamic dropdown value**.

Do you have any idea?

At this link [how to create event handler for  dynamic drop down list in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649357/how-to-create-event-handler-for-dynamic-drop-down-list-in-c-sharp) 
one solution likes below

```
ddlFilter.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged);
ddlFilter.AutoPostBack = true;

void ddlFilter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code 
}
```

Shortly,
I want to build more than one dynamic dropdown and assume that 3 dropdown and I want to handle their `selectedindexchange` events in order to interact between themselves.

Comment: If number of dropdownlists are constant, is it not possible to specify them directly on the page and use visible property..

Answer (score 0):

If i m getting your Query!!
You can use Items array of dropdownlist and loop through it and check the condition and do the changes in the items list of another dropdownlists on selected index changed.