# Dependant dropdownlist(cascading)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an existing dropdownlist that lists names.

I am trying to create another drop down list that contaings all Alphabets

What i am trying to accomplish is:

When a user selects an alphabet from the Alphabet Dropsownlist, the second dropdwonlist will populate all the names that start with the selected Alphabets.

I had this code.

```
`NamesDropDownList.SelectedValue = (NamesDropDownList.DataValueField).Where(NamesDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value).Contains(AlphabetsDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value);`
```

but it is giving me an error:

```
Error Message: string does not contain a definition of Where, and the method overload contains invalid arguments.
```

Any Help Or approach to this problem.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with that one line of code.  Let's start with the source of the data.  This is not the source of your data:

```
NamesDropDownList.DataValueField
```

That's just a `string` property on a `DropDownList`.  You can't select records from *that*, you have to select them from the *database* (or wherever your backing data is).  You haven't provided that context, so I'm going to suppose it's some standard LINQ-queryable data source.  Let's say, for the sake or example, that it's something like this:

```
dbContext.Names
```

*That* is what you'd attach a "where" clause to in order to select data.  So now let's move on to that clause and see what it looks like.  For starters, it *doesn't* look like this:

```
.Where(NamesDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value).Contains(AlphabetsDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value)
```

The `.Where()` method doesn't expect a `string`, it expects a `Func<T, bool>` as a predicate.  *Inside* that predicate is where you'd have your `.Contains()`, which would operate on the *string* and not on the *whole collection*.  So it might look something like this:

```
dbContext.Names.Where(n => n.Name.Contains(AlphabetsDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value))
```

What this line of code essentially does is:

> From the `Names` table in the database, select all records where the `Name` column contains the given value.

That would give you the filtered set of records from the data source, which could then be used to bind to the next `DropDownList`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, You are a genius, this is the method that gets the names`public IEnumerable<Job> GetAllNamesPlusUnknown() { using (var repo = RepositoryFactory.Create()) { var allNames = repo.Matches(new AllName()); var rv = new List<Name>() { new Name("<Unknown>") }; rv.AddRange(allname.Select(j => new Name(j.Name))); return rv; } }` should i be using this and work on it, the project is really interrealted, and wasn't designed for that bu the Name list might get so long that populating the List By choosing the letter will save scrolling through about 2000 names.

Comment: @user5711432: Well, it's really up to you how you get the data from the database (or wherever it's stored).  This `GetAllNamesPlusUnknown` method does return an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can attach a `.Where()` to the returned value and essentially treat this method as the backing data for this operation.

Comment: I tried to get data using ObjectDataSource, But I had no luck, I used Sql datasource and I was able to get the Alphabet, Names get Populated using above method(objectDatasource), doYou think it is wise to be consistent in getting the data, Basically use objectdataSouce for both, this  gets Alphabets`public IEnumerable<GroupAlphabets> GetAllAlphabets() {using (var repo = RepositoryFactory.Create())
{ var allalphabets = repo.Matches(new AllAlphabets());
var al = new List<GroupAlphabets>() { new GroupAlphabets() };
return al;}}` and returned it in the code behind what do you thin the problem is?

Comment: @user5711432: It sounds like there is more to your design than what's evident in the question, and you may have multiple problems to solve here.  Ultimately your controls have to be binding to *something*.  If it's a method, for example, then you can include that `.Where()` clause in the result of that method.  Any `IEnumerable<T>` can be filtered with `.Where()`.

Comment: I was trying to accomplish this using SqlDS, Because Object datasource is Not working.You are right the design is complex. but this what binds the data`private void GetItemCreateIfMissing(Guid id)
{InstalledItemsController ctl = new InstalledItemsController();
 InstalledItem installedItem = ctl.GetItemByIdCreateIfMissing(id, UserInfo.Profile.PreferredTimeZone, DateTime.UtcNow, JobNamesDropDownList.SelectedValue, UserId);
            if (installedItem != null)
            {NewNoteButton.Enabled = true;
              NamesDropDownList.SelectedValue = installedItem.Name;` any ideasThank u man

Comment: thank you for you help, I solved the problem using Javascript, I had never used it before, Bu It Came In handy for this particular Problem, the code is too long, But i am happy to help if any needs help in solving a similar problem. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Look into creating an event handler on the parent DDL

[Dynamic DDL Event Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649357/how-to-create-event-handler-for-dynamic-drop-down-list-in-c-sharp)

[DropDownList Change Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415250/c-sharp-dropdownlist-change-event)

Answer (score 0):

Just have the SelectedIndexChanged() event handler from the alphabet dropdownlist populate the names list:

```
private DataSet GetNameData()
{
        string sql = "select Firstname, Lastname from Names where Firstname like '@Letter%';";

        SqlParameter arg = new SqlParamter("@Letter", ddlLetter.SelectedItem.Value));

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand, sql, ConnectionString);
        cmd.Paramters.Add(arg);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds);

        return ds;
}
private void ddlLetter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet Names = GetNameData();

    ddlNames.DataSource = Names.Table[0];
    ddlNames.DataTextField = "Firstname";
    ddlNames.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddlNames.DataBind();

    ddlNames.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select a name", 0);
}
```

Make sure you have the alphabet dropdownlist set with `AutoPostBack="true"` otherwise it won't work.

Hope this helps!